# Setting ng-model dynamically inside ng-repeat with radio button not working, when same with input type="number" working properly

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ngmodel

I am using ng-repeat where I have to put ng-model in dynamic way. Code is as follow;

```
<div class="panel panel-default" ng-repeat="(key, value) in $parent.shared.sourceSchema">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse1">
            {{value.sourceName}}
        </a>
        </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div ng-repeat="col in value.columns">
                <input ng-model=$parent.value[sourceSrNo] type="radio">{{col.column}}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My **$parent.shared.sourceSchema** is as follow;

```
Object {1: Object}
   1:Object
       columns:Array[7]
       sourceName:"S3"
       sourceSrNo:1
       __proto__:Object
```

But the at  the applied ng-model is not working.

I tried in different way as follow;

```
ng-model=$parent.value[sourceSrNo];
ng-model=value[sourceSrNo];
ng-model={{$parent.value[sourceSrNo]}};
ng-model={{value[sourceSrNo]}};
ng-model=$parent.value.sourceSrNo;
ng-model=value.sourceSrNo;
ng-model={{$parent.value.sourceSrNo}};
ng-model={{value.sourceSrNo}};

ng-model="$parent.value[sourceSrNo]";
ng-model="value[sourceSrNo]";
ng-model="{{$parent.value[sourceSrNo]}}";
ng-model="{{value[sourceSrNo]}}";
ng-model="$parent.value.sourceSrNo";
ng-model="value.sourceSrNo";
ng-model="{{$parent.value.sourceSrNo}}";
ng-model="{{value.sourceSrNo}}";
```

None of those worked for me.

I want to keep same ng-model value for each outer ng-repeat

the result of **ng-model="$parent.value.sourceSrNo"** is as follow;

[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137222/discussion-on-question-by-kousik-mandal-setting-ng-model-dynamically-inside-ng-r).

Answer (score 0):

try to rplace
  $parent.value[sourceSrNo]
with 
value.sourceSrNo